# Setting Datetimepicker to a default time issue in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-10, datetimepicker

I have a really crazy behaviour in IE 10 when I try to initialize the date-time-picker.
Using jQuery (v 1.9.0), I navigate to the respective element to set a predefined value afterwards.
The code works perfectly in Safari, Chrome and Firefox but crashes in IE 10.

The issue occoures at:

```
datetime_field = parent.find("input:first");
```

Here the find method cannot be found for the parent object??, but I have absolutely no clue why this could possibly happen (especially because its only IE related..)?

```
function initWithDate(el) {
    dateString = dateFormat(new Date(), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss");
    parent = el.closest("div.date-time-picker-wrapper");
    datetime_field = parent.find("input:first");
    if (datetime_field.length && datetime_field.val().length)
    {
        dateString = datetime_field.val();
    }
        reggex = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;
    dateArray = reggex.exec(dateString);
        parentElement.find(".date_picker").datepicker('setDate', new Date(dateArray[1], (dateArray[2] - 1), dateArray[3]));
    parentElement.find(".timepicker_default").val(dateArray[4] + ":" + dateArray[5] + ":" + dateArray[6]);

    setNewDateTimeValue(el);
    var datetimepicker = $("#campaign_timezone");
    if (datetimepicker.val() == "" || datetimepicker.val() == undefined)
    {
        datetimepicker.select2("val", datetimepicker.find("option:contains('"+get_time_zone_name().split("/")[1]+"')").val());
        datetimepicker.val(datetimepicker.find("option:contains('"+get_time_zone_name().split("/")[1]+"')").val());
    }

}
```

Any help appreciated!